# Persistant Data requirement

Tags: android

How to add trial period for application ? does Android LVL help?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html):

> For example, an application can check
>   the licensing status and then apply
>   custom constraints that allow the user
>   to run it unlicensed for a specific
>   number of times, or for a specific
>   validity period.

License Verification Library would be a way to go.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can give for free a licensed application. The market disallows it if it's defined in the manifest.